# My HTC One M9 has a pattern lock that I forgot (I know, dumb). Used Android Device Manager. No prompt

Tags: pattern-lock

So the screen actually appears saying "Locked by Android Device Manager" but I have absolutely no prompt to type or a keyboard or anything. Hitting the home button just brings the pattern back up. I would much prefer not having to factory reset this phone. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What os version is your phone? If it's kitkat, it should have a Forgot pattern below it if you don't draw the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my blog check this out...

https://techicraze.wordpress.com/2015/12/16/hack-android-pattern-or-password/

Helpful if rooted only

You just have to remove "gesture.key" file from your system and then reboot mobile and then any pattern you draw will unlock the mobile.